# Cookies shared between Office365 and my app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, owin

I've a webapp developed with ASP.NET MVC using Microsoft authentication (so handled with OWIN, OpenIdConnect). If the user in the browser is already logged in Office365 with his credentials, when tries to reach the login page of my webapp gets the following message:

AADSTS7000112: Application 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'(AppName) is disabled.

Is possible not sharing the cookie between Office365 and my app?

Comment: Usually, you can't share cookies between different applications. In ASP.NET Core, the user cookie is encrypted using a different/separate key.

Comment: could it be the effect of SSO?

Comment: Looks more on the ID that the app registration in azureAd have some problems?